# Div 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css, height, parent

Despite looking at various different SO answers nothing seems to work. I have:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="icons">
                // icons
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

The icons container needs to be 100% height of the row but I can't for the life of me get it to work. See below, the dark blue should goto the bottom but I can't get it to work. Help?

[image]

**ANSWER:
After much messing about (fixed heights were never the answer) I opted for the One True Layout method to get equal heights on my sibling containers: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/**

Comment: The container/row setup is basically Bootstrap. I've thrown out my icons div CSS as nothing worked.

Comment: Provide a JSFIDDLE or the actual css you're using!

Comment: @MattSaunders So? You should still give us the CSS etc. If you want a fast answer thats the way to go. Had you setup a fiddle or something I would have answered it right away.

Comment: I would rather see your fresh approach to this

Comment: If your footer element has a height defined, then you can go with `.container, .row, .icons{height: 100%;}` they all will get the height of `footer`

Comment: @MattSaunders It would be a fresh approach, all you would be doing it setting up the page for us to then show you how it is done. We wouldn't give you a quick fix that isn't a good way to do it. At the moment people are just guessing, giving us something to work with will get you a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**Footer/Icons Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsLemxun/1/)

The container (`row`) must have the height specified then adjust the `icon` div's height to `100%`.

```
.row {
    background: blue;
    height: 250px; /* set the height of the row */
}
.icons {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%; /*set to 100% to adjust to the row height */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position:relative;` on the container/parent. And then `height:100%;` on the contained element.

If that parent is not 100% height that set that parents height to 100% and that parents parent to positio relative. continue upwards till you get your height

Comment: Just as a note, setting position:relative is not necessary if you want to set a percentage height to a div. It only depends on his parent having a defined height.

Comment: Oh thanks man I didn't know that, I always set everything relative and thought that was fixing things.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my fiddle works for you http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/zh27nfzz/

HTML :-

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="icons">
            <ul><li>Facebook</li>
                 <li>Twitter</li>    
                 <li>Pinterest</li>
                 <li>Instagram</li>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :-

```
.container{
width:500px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid;
background-color: skyblue;
}

.row{
padding-left:4px;
}

.icons{
border:1px solid;
width:490px;
background-color: darkviolet;
height: 199px;
}
```